# Electromagnetism:field and waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

What does the area under the graph of anEM wave represent?,is it the magnitude of the area of the electomagnetic field?

Comment: The electromagnetic field exists throughout space. It doesn't have an area.